# Current Period in Cellular Setting

Tags: settings

Is it possible for the "Current period" to have a value when you didn't call anyone? This is for 6s+. There's 23 minutes in Current Period, which to my understanding is the last call time. Am I correct?

Comment: Not just for the last call but the aggregate of all the calls made since last reset.

Comment: Reset statistics right? Not factory reset or restore? Is it possible to reflect a value when you didn't call anyone from last reset?

Comment: Yes, Reset Statistics. A value will be shown with aggregate of incoming and outgoing calls.